# Unable to generate a signed APK in android StaticLoggerBinder.class

Tags: java, android

I am facing below error when I try to generate APK from Studio.
Kindly help me out to solve this error.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class

Please find my gradle file

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sampleapplication"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })





    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'


}
```

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: set all com.android.support `v7:25.1.1` instead of  `v7:21.0.+,22.2.0

Comment: I tried by doing above changes. Still facing the same issue.Zip

Comment: use `compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'`